# QDataStream won’t work with custom crafted char array

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I have an application which consists of two primary modules. One is written in C, uses standard C runtime library and one written in Qt C++. They communicate with each other with IPC. C module creates a char array, fills it with data and sends to the module written in Qt. I want to deserialize received data using QDataStream, but my efforts didn't yield any result yet. Here's a simple example what I'm trying to achieve:

```
unsigned int pointer = 0;
const int IPC_MSG_LEN = 500;
const int IPC_MSG_HEADER = 200;
const int SOMETHING = 1443;
char api = 55;

char msg[IPC_MSG_LEN] = {0};
memcpy_s(msg, IPC_MSG_LEN, &IPC_MSG_HEADER, sizeof(int));
pointer = sizeof(unsigned int);
memcpy_s(&msg[pointer], IPC_MSG_LEN - pointer, &api, sizeof(char));
++pointer;
memcpy_s(&msg[pointer], IPC_MSG_LEN - pointer, &SOMETHING, sizeof(int));

QByteArray arr(msg, IPC_MSG_LEN);
QDataStream ds(&arr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint32 header = 0, aa = 0;
qint8 t_api = 0;
ds >> header; //Doesn't work
ds >> t_api; //Works
ds >> aa; //Doesn't work
```

As you can see, the code is pretty simple, but header and aa variables are deserialized to a random number. However t_api (one byte variable) has correct value assigned.
So what's the problem with this code? Does QDataStream uses a private data format which is not compatible with the one I'm using? Should I write my own QIODevice implementation or there is a quick fix I'm not aware of? :)
Thanks, I appreciate your help.

**UPDATE**

---

Thank you very much guys, your solution worked perfectly with those primitive data types, but the problem is that I also need to be able to serialize/deserialize char* strings too.

```
wchar_t* name1 = L"something";
memcpy_s(&msg[pointer], IPC_MSG_LEN - pointer, name1, (wcslen(name1) + 1) * 2);

char* ai = new char[500];
ds >> ai; //ai becomes NULL here :|
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QDataStream::setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
```

---

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QString>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> void writePtr(char*&dst, T data){
    *reinterpret_cast<T*>(dst) = data;
    dst += sizeof(T);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    const size_t ipcSize = 512;
    std::vector<char> buffer(ipcSize, 0);
    quint32 sendVal1 = 0x12345678, recvVal1 = 0;
    quint8 sendVal2 = 0xee, recvVal2 = 0;   
    quint32 sendVal3 = 0x9999abcd, recvVal3 = 0;
    char* dst = &buffer[0];
    writePtr(dst, sendVal1);
    writePtr(dst, sendVal2);
    writePtr(dst, sendVal3);

    QByteArray byteArray(&buffer[0]);
    QDataStream stream(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    stream >> recvVal1 >> recvVal2 >> recvVal3;

    qDebug() << QString(QObject::tr("sent: %1, received: %2")).arg(sendVal1, 8, 16).arg    (recvVal1, 8, 16);
    qDebug() << QString(QObject::tr("sent: %1, received: %2")).arg(sendVal2, 2, 16).arg(recvVal2, 2, 16);
    qDebug() << QString(QObject::tr("sent: %1, received: %2")).arg(sendVal3, 8, 16).arg(recvVal3, 8, 16);

    return 0;
}
```

---

> but the problem is that I also need to be able to serialize/deserialize char* strings too.

Qt data serialization format is explained (in detail) [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html). You **MUST** read that document if you want to use QDataStream for IPC. Qt has nice [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/), so use it.

Also this is not a char* string:

```
 wchar_t* name1 = L"something";
```

It is a `wchar_t*` string.

`wchar_t` has different size depending on compiler - either 4 or 2 bytes per wchar_t. Which means problem for IPC. unlike `wchar_t`, `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte big. 
So either encode entire string to UTF8 (or use 8bit-encoded string with known codepage/encoding) and write it as raw data in [QByteArray-compatible format](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html):

```
void writeDataPtr(char*& ptr, const char* data, quint32 size){
    if (!data){
        size = 0xffffffff;
        writePtr(ptr, size);
        return;
    }

    memcpy(ptr, data, size);
    ptr += size;
}
```

Then use `QString::fromUtf8` to decode it (or `QTextCodec` - if you decided to use other 8bit encoding instead of utf8). OR **if** you can ensure that your `wchar_t*` string is UTF16-compliant **and** `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`, dump it in [QString-compatible format](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html).

By the way - If I were you, I'd avoid `memcpy_s`. It is not part of C++ standard, which is a very good reason to avoid it.

---

> I want is to read wchar_t*/char* from QDataStream until stream position gets to null terminating character.

If this is homework, tag your post accordingly.

One of those should work:

```
QString readWcharString(QDataStream& stream){
    QVector<ushort> rawData;
    ushort tmp;
    do{
        stream >> tmp;
        rawData.push_back(tmp)
    }while(tmp);
    return QString::fromUtf16(rawData.data());
}
```

or

```
QString readWcharString(QDataStream& stream){
    QVector<wchar_t> rawData;
    ushort tmp;
    do{
        stream >> tmp;
        rawData.push_back(tmp)
    }while(tmp);
    return QString::fromWCharArray(rawData.data());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. please take a look at my updated post.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how your answer can help in my situation. I'm aware of the differences between wchar_t and char, all I want is to read wchar_t*/char* from QDataStream until stream position gets to null terminating character, but I guess this is not default behavior of QDataStream, am I right?

Comment: @Davita: either modify "sender" to dump data in QDataStream compatible format, or modify receiver to read "non-standard" data using QDataStream. Reading wchar_t characters from QDataStream with >> until you get character that is == 0 has "homework" difficulty and is matter of adding one subroutine that has 5 lines of code. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`QDataStream` stores the numbers in the big endian format by default. 

You can change that with:

```
ds.setByteOrder(QDataStream::ByteOrder(QSysInfo::ByteOrder));
```

which will use the detected host endianness instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. please take a look at my updated post.